# Lua OOP. How to inherit tables from a prototype

Tags: lua, prototype

In *Programming in Lua* I found an example to work with inheritance. I understood how it is handled through metatable `__index` but when I made my own example where one of the items to inherit is a table I realised the table is shared by new created objects:

```lua
Account = {
    balance = 0,
    info = {},
    withdraw = function (self, v)
        self.balance = self.balance - v
    end,
    deposit = function (self, v)
        self.balance = self.balance + v
    end,
    add = function (self, item)
        if self:check(item) then return end
        table.insert(self.info, item)
    end,
    remove = function (self, item)
        table.remove(self.info, item)
    end,
    check = function (self, item)
        for i, v in ipairs(self.info) do
            if v == item then return true end
        end
    end,
    new = function (self, o)
        o = o or {}
        self.__index = self
        setmetatable(o, self)
        return o
    end,
}

local a1 = Account:new()
local a2 = Account:new()
local a3 = Account:new()


a1:deposit(50)
a1:add("aaa")
a2:deposit(100)
a2:add("bbb")
a2:add("bbb")

print(a1.balance)
for _, v in ipairs(a1.info) do print(v) end
print(a2.balance)
for _, v in ipairs(a2.info) do print(v) end
```

Here `info` is shared by all objects:

```
50
aaa
bbb
100
aaa
bbb
```

How can I make info unique in each new objects?

EDIT. The workaround is I put all "fields" to the method `new` whilst left methods in a prototype but I don't see it is very elegant:

```lua
    new = function (self, o)
        o = o or {}
        o.balance = 0
        o.info = {}
        self.__index = self
        setmetatable(o, self)
        return o
    end,
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer might be easier than you think; you assign `info` in the "class" table. Instead, just assign a new `info` table to every instance in the constructor:

```lua
function Account:new(instance)
   instance = instance or {}
   instance.info = {}
   setmetatable(instance, self)
   return instance
end
```

---

Note that, in my example, I've removed the line `self.__index = self` because you shouldn't be doing that in the constructor. Instead, assign it once after you've created the table as `Account.__index=Account`

Comment: The example comes from *Programming in Lua* ed.4 but I have added the table `info`. I thought `__index` is required in a metatable (here Account) in order for a new object `instance` to find a substitute for a missing key in the `instance`. `Account` in your example doesn't have `__index`. Why don't you need it?

Comment: I've edited what looked like a typo in this answer (`__info` -> `__index`). @Celdor, does this explain it for you?

Comment: I see. Yes, it is clearer what you have explained in the answer. Thanks. Now it is only me wondering what difference it makes between your suggestion and self.__index=self inside new. I’m learning these things and probably am missing something but to me self in the method new holds the address of Account. In the end, both approaches set the same meta table.

Comment: the difference is when and how often the value in the metatable is set. You only really need it once but you're doing it again for every new instance — @luther indeed that was a typo, thanks for fixing it :D

Comment: It makes sense now. Thanks.